# Running flask and python with CGI

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask, cgi

I registered a domain and it allows the use of CGI scripts. But I don't know how to run flask + python with the script.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/cgi/ gives a decent description of what to do but still was unable to get flask and python to run. My python file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
```

Also the cgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from yourapplication import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

And the htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex Home.html

# Begin EnforceSSL double-numbersign-freelancer.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?double-numbersign-freelancer.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
# End EnforceSSL
```

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520175/run-python-cgi-application-on-heroku

Comment: And what is the content of your CGI script?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from yourapplication import app

CGIHandler().run(app)

Comment: Also it looks like I need to edit .htaccess file?

Comment: Do you really need to use CGI technology? You can use application servers for flask → uwsgi, gunicorn... Also there is wsgi module for Apache ( https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/ ). I guess that is more standard way to run flask applications.

Comment: I'm really not sure what is  available but there is a cgi and scripting section at www.domain.com/help. I will ask the site

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I checked it

Answering for my configuration → `CentOS 7 / httpd 2.4.6`

1. Open `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and add python handler

```
# standard part
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
```

```
# add handler here
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

```
</Directory>
```

2. Put `run.py` inside `/var/www/cgi-bin`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'

@app.route('/suburl')
def index2():
    return '<h1>Hello World 2!</h1>'

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

3. Change script permissions to allow execution:

```sh
chmod +x /var/www/cgi-bin/run.py
```

4. Now you can access:

```
http://your_server_url.com/cgi-bin/run.py → Hello World!
http://your_server_url.com/cgi-bin/run.py/suburl → Hello World 2!
```

Huh. That was my first experience with Flask CGI. Pretty simple and good for small or test projects.
Anyway I recommend to use [`gunicorn`](https://gunicorn.org), [`uwsgi`](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [`mod_wsgi`](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for apache in production.

- **EDIT1: Using CGI without flask**

Actually you don't need flask for run CGI scripts. It can be written with any language that can read environment variables and output some data.

Bash example `/var/www/cgi-bin/run.cgi`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "Content-type:text/plain"
echo
echo -e "HELLO WORLD\nYour URL path is $PATH_INFO"
```

Output will be:

```
http://example.com/cgi-bin/run.cgi/suburl
```

```
HELLO WORLD
Your URL path is /suburl
```

Comment: I talked to domain.com and they say flask isnt able to be used there

Comment: I believe the Apache module is called mod_wsgi.